# regex implementation to replace group with its lowercase version

Tags: regex, replace, lowercase

Is there any implementation of regex that allow to replace group in regex with lowercase version of it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Perl, you can do:

```
$string =~ s/(some_regex)/lc($1)/ge;
```

The `/e` option causes the replacement expression to be interpreted as Perl code to be evaluated, whose return value is used as the final replacement value.  `lc($x)` returns the lowercased version of `$x`.  (Not sure but I assume `lc()` will handle international characters correctly in recent Perl versions.)

`/g` means match globally.  Omit the `g` if you only want a single replacement.

Comment: Perl also supports `\L` syntax, e.g. `s/(some_regex)/\L$1/g`, tested on 5.26.

Answer (score 63):

If your regex version supports it, you can use \L, like so in a POSIX shell:

```
sed -r 's/(^.*)/\L\1/'
```

Comment: This appears to work in a surprising number of regex kits, even if you're not in a shell-like environment.

Comment: @Tim: Agreed, even Notepad++ supports it.

Comment: This does not work in `zsh` or `bash` on OSX (yes I'm using `-E` instead of `-r`).

Comment: BSD sed is too limited. On OS X use Homebrew and install gnu-sed instead. Then it works.

Comment: Works in Linux's `rename` command, which at least in Ubuntu 14 is a perl script (/usr/bin/prename).

Comment: Since `*` is greedy and `.` stands for any character, you don't have to anchor the pattern with `^`. With gnu sed, you can also remove the capture group and the -r switch and write: `sed 's/.*/\L&/'`. On the other hand writing `sed --posix 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/'` doesn't work with gnu sed (and add a L at the start of the line).

Comment: Just want to add that the \L works in VS Code as well. My replace regex is `$1\L$2` which keeps group 1 as it is, but change group 2 to lowercase.

Answer (score 23):

If you're using an editor like SublimeText or TextMate<sup>1</sup>, there's a good chance you may use

```
\L$1
```

as your replacement, where `$1` refers to something from the regular expression that you put parentheses around.  For example<sup>2</sup>, here's something I used to downcase field names in some SQL, getting everything to the right of the 'as' at the end of any given line.  First the "find" regular expression:

```
(as|AS) ([A-Za-z_]+)\s*,$
```

and then the replacement expression:

```
$1 '\L$2',
```

If you use Vim (or presumably gvim), then you'll want to use `\L\1` instead of `\L$1`, but there's another wrinkle that you'll need to be aware of: Vim reverses the syntax between literal parenthesis characters and escaped parenthesis characters.  So to designate a part of the regular expression to be included in the replacement ("captured"), you'll use `\(` at the beginning and `\)` at the end.  Think of `\` as—instead of escaping a special character to make it a literal—marking the beginning of a special character (as with `\s`, `\w`, `\b` and so forth).  So it may seem odd if you're not used to it, but it is actually perfectly logical if you think of it in the Vim way.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've tested this in both TextMate and SublimeText and it works as-is, but some editors use `\1` instead of `$1`.  Try both and see which your editor uses.

<sup>2</sup> I just pulled this regex out of my history.  I always tweak regexen while using them, and I can't promise this the final version, so I'm not suggesting it's fit for the purpose described, and especially not with SQL formatted differently from the SQL I was working on, just that it's a specific example of downcasing in regular expressions.  YMMV.  UAYOR.

Comment: Nice, Intellij IDEA supports this too

Answer (score 17):

Several answers have noted the use of `\L`. However, `\E` is also worth knowing about if you use `\L`.

> `\L` converts everything up to the next `\U` or `\E` to lowercase. ... `\E` turns off case conversion.
>
> *(Source: https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html )*

So, suppose you wanted to use [`rename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL) to lowercase part of some file names like this:

```
artist_-_album_-_Song_Title_to_be_Lowercased_-_MultiCaseHash.m4a
artist_-_album_-_Another_Song_Title_to_be_Lowercased_-_MultiCaseHash.m4a
```

you could do something like:

```
rename -v 's/^(.*_-_)(.*)(_-_.*.m4a)/$1\L$2\E$3/g' *
```

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, there's

```
$string =~ tr/[A-Z]/[a-z]/;
```

Comment: The [A-Z]? It was an example. That said, I voted for j_random_hacker's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most Regex implementations allow you to pass a callback function when doing a replace, hence you can simply return a lowercase version of the match from the callback.