# Android Studio regex replace with Lowercase

Tags: android, regex, lowercase

How can I convert the matched group to a lower case when doing find and replace?
I tried $L$1 to replace the first match to a lowercase for no avail. $1 works but does not convert the text to a lowercase.

Thank you

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Apple to apple: Find  ^([A-Z]) Replace $L$1 does not work,

Comment: @samjesse I think what you want is not possible in Android Studio. Note that most editors/IDE's can't do this kind of replacement as well. So you're better off using a scripting language or use an editor that supports this. I think notepad++ can do the job.

Comment: Use SublimeText http://stackoverflow.com/a/21313098/1649615

Comment: Use Notepad++ or SublimeText, Android Studio does not allow case modifying operators in the replacement pattern.